# Как отобразить содержимое большого количества файлов в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

Есть папка внутри которой есть большое кол-во папок(имя папки это дата создания), внутри каждой папки есть большое кол-во текстовых файлов(может быть как несколько файлов так и несколько тысяч, со временем будут появляться новые файлы), имена файлов по следующему принципу: имя_источника.время_создания.log

**Задача следующая:**
нужно сделать программу просмоторщик содержимого(как в реальном так и в заданных рамках времени) всех файлов в зависимости от выбранного имени источника.

подгружать содержимое всех файлов будет накладно и возможно даже не хватит памяти(суммарный размер может быть в десятки Гб).
Я так понял мне нужно сделать свои классы от **QTableView и QAbstractTableModel**.
Но проблема в связывании скролла и отображаемых данных в табилце, а также подгрузке нужных файлов в зависимости от положения скролла.

Я решил отключить встроенный скролл таблицы, а рядом с таблицей поставить свой созданный в setRange которого передавать суммарный размер всех нужных файлов. В зависимости от того куда я поставлю ползунок через расчёты размеров файлов и папок искать нужный файл(содержимое которого я буду уже подгружать в память) и нужную строку чтобы начиная с неё отображать в окне, также переопределить wheelEvent таблицы и внутри него уже менять значения своего скролла,и соответственно отображаемых строк в таблице(если доходим до конца/начала файла, то подгружаем новый, попутно выгружая из памяти предыдущий).

**Наконец сам вопрос:** Можно ли в Qt все описанное сделать проще и быстрее или уже делать по тому принципу что я описал(мб есть ссылки на хорошие статейки или примеры на эту тему, потому что мои поиски особо результата не дали)? Мб мне и QAbstractTableModel в таком случае не понадобится.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в Qt Creator'e нечто подобное реализовано для QTextEdit'ов, в которые выводится содержимое вывода сборки. Можно посмотреть исходники. Почему QTableView - подгружать нужно CSV файлы?

Comment: @EugenyShtanov Обычные текстовые файлы, но структура строки подразумевает разбиение на столбцы. В последствии добавится возможность фильтрации данных(к примеру вывести только те строки, в которых в 3 столбце был определённый символ). Поэтому внешне выглядеть должно как таблица, а QTableView, если я правильно понял, как раз подходит под это.

Comment: Извините за задержку - я пытался разобраться, но времени пока не нашел. В Qt Creator'e есть класс - ConsoleEdit, наследуемый от QTextEdit, реализующий отображение делегатов ConsoleItemDelegate через QAbstractItemModel. Там тоже выводимый текст формируется на основе позиции ползунка прокрутки. ИМХО, Вам нужно нечто подобное, только с отображением в QTableView вместо QTextEdit.

Comment: @EugenyShtanov Спасибо, посмотрю в исходниках как там реализовано